# Angularjs: highlight selected range in datepicker hover

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to simulate a similiar effect as [Kayak](http://www.kayak.com/) does in his datepicker. When you select a Depart date and then go to return date, see that the date range is highlighted when you hover a single date.

For this, i'm using a customized version of an [angular datepicker](https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker) and have tried things like asigning the date i'm hovering to ng-mouseover directeve and then a condition in the ng-class directive like (hover-date > depart-date), but this just add the class to the hovered date and not to the complete range (the thing that does right is not adding the class when you hovered dates before the depart-date).

Hope i'm being clear, tell me if not.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?